# Measurability of point processes

Tags: point-processes

I am reading the "Construction of Diffusion processes with Wentzell's Boundary conditions by means of poisson point processes of Browninan excursions" of S. Watanabe and he says:[image]

I understand that to say that $N_p((0,t]\times U)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ adapted means $$\forall a >0\qquad\{\omega\mid N_{p(\omega)}((0,t]\times U))>a\} \in \mathcal{F}_t $$ But what does it mean to say that $\{N_p((0,t]\times U)\}_{U \in \mathbb{B}(X)}$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ adapted?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I make sense of this is that for all $U \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ and $t$ it is required to be true that the random variables $f_{U, t}$ given by
$$f_{U, t}(\omega) = N_{p(\omega)}((0, t] \times U)$$
are $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable.  I have placed $U$ and $t$ in the subscript of $f$ to highlight the dependence of its definition on those two parameters.

Comment: It is the same as the first sentence I wrote ?

Comment: In a way.  If you instead define $$f_t(\omega) = N_{p(\omega)}((0,t]\times U)$$ then $f_t$ can be considered an adapted process.

Comment: @ConradoCosta - I realized given your questions I had misread the original question.  I've modified my answer.

Comment: I see. Anyway, it is strange  to use such a notation, One often writes $\{B_t\}_t$ to mean the brownian process. So $\{N_p((0,t]\times U)\}_{U \in \mathbb{B}(X)}$ is a strange object...

Comment: @ConradoCosta Agreed.